# how do I add a path to a file in this .bashrc file

Tags: bash

I have this .bashrc file

```
#PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
export PS1="\u @\w >"

#redefine a command to add options
alias mv='mv -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias df='df -h'
alias du='du -h'
alias mkdir='mkdir -p'
alias ls='ls -lahG'
export LESS='-N'
```

I have this .bash_login file

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a     shell session *as a function*
```

I have this .bash_profile file

```
#This file only runs when user first logs in

#[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
#export PS1="\u @\w >"

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

I want to add this path to my $PATH variable so that the system can locate the program.

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/
```

Which file should I add this to?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your .bash_login is doing anything (bash only runs that if .bash_profile doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type in your .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: It never hurts to dbl-quote the values being to a variable. Then you don't have to worry about spaces in the existing PATH value. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I put environment-related stuff in `.bash_profile`